# Changing a 1.8 Maven Project to compile to 1.16 produces "invalid target release 1.16"

Tags: java, maven, build, compilation, upgrade

I've been searching a solution for hours, couldn't even find 1 post about maven compilation to 1.16

I recently decided to one of my projects from java 8 to 16, so I installed 16 JDK and changed my build section(in pom.xml) accordingly:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.16</source> //used to be 1.8
                <target>1.16</target> //used to be 1.8
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I get the following error when I try to install:

```
[INFO] Total time:  0.628 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-03T22:40:27+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project employeme: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.16 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please check what `mvn --version` shows? There should be an output information about JDK16 if it's not what I expect.. you have to change your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to JDK16 to build with JDK 16....

Comment: How to run this command from Eclipse? Also I already put my JAVA_HOME to jdk 16... didn't work

Comment: Plain command line not from within Eclipse...does not really makes sense...

Comment: cmd doesn't recognize "mvn"...

Comment: You have to install Maven of course to run it.... https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and install it: https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not `1.16`, it's `16`.
2. You don't have to configure the `maven-compiler-plugin`.
3. You can use [the new `release` option](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version).

```xml
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>16</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Even after changing both release & target to 16 I still get "Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 16 -> [Help 1]"
Also, I do need the compiler plugin because java version isn't the only thing I set.

Comment: @David What's your JDK version? If I run `javac -target 16 test.java` on JDK 11 on the cmd line I get `error: invalid target release: 16`, too.

Comment: as I wrote in the post... I installed jdk 16, and running your command works for me

Comment: @David What is selected in _Eclipse_ → _Preferences_ → _Java_ → _Installed JREs_? What if you build on the cmd line rather than from within Eclipse?

Comment: @David Isn't it clear for you from that screenshot? You're telling Eclipse that you just have JDK 8 installed and expect it to compile for JDK 16? So, _Add..._ JDK 16 there and add it to the build path of your project (as mentioned in the dialog's description). Re `mvn` on cmd line: Most probably `<Maven home>\bin` isn't in your system's PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue despite the fact that my settings were

```
<source>16</source> //used to be 8
<target>16</target> //used to be 8
```

The real insight came up when I ran

```
mvn --version
```

as this one pointed out I was running a current maven with JDK 11.

The solution was to change JAVA_HOME to point to my JDK 16 installation before running maven.